# Why NULL is converted to string*?

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, overload-resolution

I saw the following code:

```
class NullClass {
public:
    template<class T> operator T*() const { return 0; }
};

const NullClass NULL;

void f(int x);
void f(string *p);

f(NULL); // converts NULL to string*, then calls f(string*)
```

Q1> I have problems to understand the following statement

```
template<class T> operator T*() const { return 0; }
```

Specially, what is the meaning of `operator T*()`?

Q2> Why `f(NULL)` is finally triggering the `f(string*)`?

Thank you

Comment: It's best not to name a variable "`NULL`" The name is reserved, and if you include any of the standard library headers, it may be defined as a macro (expanding to `0` or something equivalent).

Comment: +1. I'd say that to make it compile in real project (that definitely includes some standard libraries) he needs to add `#undef NULL` in the code that will 99% lead to "interesting" results.

Comment: For what it's worth, you should be using something more like [this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/nullptr). That's how the C++0x `nullptr` works.

Comment: i will not do this in a real project:)

Comment: Hello all, one more question is as follows: when we call f(NULL) without<string> template signature, how does the compiler know this? - thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> what is the meaning of `operator T*()`?

It is a user-defined conversion operator.  It allows an object of type `NullClass` to be converted to any pointer type.

Such conversion operators can often lead to subtle, unexpected, and pernicious problems, so they are best avoided in most cases (they are, of course, occasionally useful).

> Why `f(NULL)` is finally triggering the `f(string*)`?

`NULL` is of type `NullClass`.  It can't be converted to an `int`, but the user-defined conversion `NullClass -> T*` can be used to convert it to a `string*`, so `void f(string*)` is selected.

Note that this works because there is only one overload of `f` that takes a pointer.  If you had two overloads,

```
void f(int*);
void f(float*);
```

the call would be ambiguous because the `NullClass -> T*` conversion can be converted to both `int*` and `float*`.

Comment: Note that this ambiguity would also exist when using the traditional `NULL` value: `0`.

Comment: Hi James, I like what you mentioned "NULL is of type NullClass. It can't be converted to an int"! -- thank you

Answer (score 2):

`template<class T> operator T*()` means that there is an implicit conversion from `NullClass` to `T*` for any `T`.

When you're calling `f(NULL)`, the compiler needs to decide which overload to use. Since neither overload takes an object of type `NullClass`, it looks which implicit conversions exist. There is no conversion to `int`, but there is one to `string*`, so the conversion is applied and the `string*` overload is called.

Answer (score 2):

1. `operator Anything()` overloads the "cast" operator. Whenever NullClass needs to be converted to Anything, this function will be called, and the result will be used.

   In your case, Anything is `T*` where T can be any type (it is a template parameter), meaning a NullClass supports casting to any pointers.
2. Since NullClass can be cast into any pointers, including a `string*`. So the `f(string*)` version will be used.

Answer (score 2):

> Q1> I have problems to understand the following statement
>
> ```
> template<class T> operator T*() const { return 0; }
> ```
>
> Specially, what is the meaning of `operator T*()`?

It's an implicit conversion operator. It makes it possible to have objects of the type it belongs to implicit convert to the target type `T*` here. This version is a special one, since, being a template, it can convert an object of that `NullClass` to ***any*** pointer type.
Implicit conversion are frowned upon for good reasons. They have the bad habit of kicking in at unexpected moments, making the compiler call an unintended version of an overloaded function. Having a templatized implicit conversion operator is especially evil because templatization multiplies the possibilities.

> Q2> Why f(NULL) is finally triggering the f(string*)?

See above. There is no possible conversion to `int`, so the implicit conversion operator kicks in and converts an `NullClass` object into any pointer requested.
I suppose this is intended. Usually you don't want a pointer to be converted to an integer, which is why that class has an implicit conversion into any pointer, but none to `int`.

---

That `NullClass` isn't all that bad, but the `NULL` instance of it is pure stupidity. As soon as you include any of the many headers that define the `NULL` macro (defined to be `0`, i.e. an integer constant), the preprocessor will trample over all source and replace each usage of `NULL` with `0`. Since you can't avoid to include this, this error renders the whole class pretty much useless.

Answer (score 1):

The NuLLClass provides a conversion function to convert to a pointer. When you call `f(NULL)`, it will try to find a way to convert NULL to a valid argument for f.

Because you can call `operator T*()` on NULL, it will with T=string. This fulfills the demand for `f(string *)`. Since there is no way to convert NULL to an int, there is only one clear choice of which function to call.

Answer (score 1):

> Specially, what is the meaning of `operator T*()`?

It is a conversion operator to type `T*`. It allows operations such as `(T*)NULL`.

> Q2> Why f(NULL) is finally triggering the f(string*)?

Because the compiler looks for the best match between the arguments and the method's signature, in this case choosing `template<typename T> NullClass::operator T*()`, where `T=string`.